# Converting Keras Model, which contains ELU, to TFlite

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras

I have compiled keras .h5 model, which contains ELU activation layer, and I converted it with freeze_graph.py so I have .pb file.

To use .pb file in Android, I tried to convert it to TFlite file using "toco" [Codes that I used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632152/tensorflow-convert-pb-file-to-tflite-using-python) but I am getting an error:

```
I tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1080] Converting unsupported operation: Elu
Here is a list of operators for which  you will need custom implementations: Elu
```

Is there any way to use ELU activation function?

I am not sure how to deal with the custom implementation to support ELU.