# How can I convert a saved .pb model to TFLITE?

Tags: tensorflow, model, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

I have a model trained with TF 1.4 exported to a frozen inference graph with the file "models/research/object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py"

How can I can convert it tflite? I'm having a lot of issues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow Convert pb file to TFLITE using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632152/tensorflow-convert-pb-file-to-tflite-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [command line tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/r1/convert/cmdline_examples.md) or the [Python API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/r1/convert/python_api.md).

Python API example:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

CLI example:

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=/tmp/foo.tflite \
  --graph_def_file=/tmp/mobilenet_v1_0.50_128/frozen_graph.pb \
  --input_arrays=input \
  --output_arrays=MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Tensorflow officially recommends using the Python API.