# How to convert .pb file to .tflite. in tensorflow 2.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

I have trained my model using **SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 640x640** and **tensorflow 2.1.0**. To create .pb file used file *export_tflite_graph_tf2.py*. Now , want to convert .pb file to .tflite.
I used following code code recommended by tensorflow community .But it is converting the model to 1kb tflite file.

I tried also using tf-nightly  but same converts into 1kb

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: The same question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647695/12124188)

Comment: Its about tf 1.x . I tried those code .

Comment: Try in [command line](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#command_line_tool_) option to convert to tflite model and see the difference.Thanks!

Comment: thanks ...there was issue with tensorflow 2.1 .. Whent tried with tf-2.3.0 it resolved .