# How to know Tensorflow Lite model's input/output feature info?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I'm mobile developer. And I want to use various Tensorflow Lite models(`.tflite`) with [MLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/).

But there are some issues, I have no idea of how to know `.tflite` model's input/output feature info(these will be parameters for setup).

Is there any way to know that?

Sorry for bad English and thanks.

---

Update(18.06.13.):

I found this site https://lutzroeder.github.io/Netron/.
This visualize graph based on your uploaded model(like `.mlmode` or `.tflite` etc.) and find input/output form.

Here is example screenshot!
[https://lutzroeder.github.io/Netron example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6V6E.png)

Comment: When you create the `tflite` model, you need to know the input and output types and shapes. And that is all the info you need to run the model in ML Kit. How are you creating the tflite model?

Comment: @PannagSanketi Thanks for replay. I downloaded from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/demo_android), MobileNet. I know about that if I try to find MobileNet's interface features info, I can find from webpage and papers.. But my question is whether I have input / output info in the model. (The Core ML model has those meta info)

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already have a tflite model that you did not produce yourself, and you 
**want to look inside the tflite file and understand your inputs and outputs**, you can use `flatc` tool and convert
the model to `.json` file and read that.

First clone the flatbuffers repo and build flatc.

```
git clone https://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git
```

Then you have to have the tensorflow schema.fbs stored locally. Either checkout the tensorflow github or download
that [one file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/18003982ff9c809ab8e9b76dd4c9b9ebc795f4b8/tensorflow/contrib/lite/schema/schema.fbs). 
Then you can run `flatc` to generate the `json` file from then input tflite model.

```
flatc -t schema.fbs -- input_model.tflite
```

This will create a `input_model.json` file that can be easily read.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer what I want!
Thanks again helpful hint!

Comment: I'm getting an error in the schema definition:
error: schema.fbs:7: 1: error: illegal character: <

any ideas?

Comment: The schema file mentioned above is wrong. This one seems to be working: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/lite/schema/schema.fbs

Comment: Unfortunately the json file is a bunch of gibberish. I still don't know the expected input and output dimensions of the network

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer:

See these instructions for building:

https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__building.html

> If you already have a tflite model that you did not produce yourself,
>   and you want to look inside the tflite file and understand your inputs
>   and outputs, you can use flatc tool and convert the model to .json
>   file and read that.
>
> First clone the flatbuffers repo and build flatc.
>
> `git clone https://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git`
>
> Then you have to have the tensorflow schema.fbs stored locally. Either        checkout the
>   tensorflow github or download that one file. Then you can run flatc to
>   generate the json file from then input tflite model.
>
> ```
> flatc -t schema.fbs -- input_model.tflite
> ```
>
> This will create a input_model.json file that can be easily read.