# how to check the quantized weights in tflite files

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

When I quantized the model by lite modules in `tensorflow`, I cann't check the weights values that had `quantized`.Is there any way to  view these values in the `.tflite` files? or Is there any way to parse the `.tflite` files?

Comment: Please add your program you created and issue you are facing.

Answer (score 3):

There are some neural network visualizers that can also provide an interface to inspect the file. I have been using [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron). You can click on the "weights" tab of the layer you are interested in to view the data. I haven't tried it yet, but there appears to be a floppy-disk save icon when you view weights/biases in the right side-bar.

The data format is a Google FlatBuffer, defined by the schema file [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/schema/schema.fbs). You may prefer doing this if you want to do *something* with the data like output it in a different format. I found the output from parsing it myself using the schema.fbs file to match Netron's for the CNN's I passed in. You can check out the FlatBuffers documentation [here](http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/).

Comment: Hi, when I use [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/Netron) to build net graph in the browser on my local host, there exits a problem that hint "Model load request failed. 404". Have you ever faced with this issue and how to solve this problem?@Aleksandr @user10530640

Comment: @William I have not used the browser mode much with Netron, sorry. A 404 error when running locally makes me suspect a server hosting issue. I would recommend trying to open your model in the desktop application to see if you get the same issue. If it still doesn't work, perhaps you can upload your model so someone can take a look? You can also try using the FlatBuffers library to inspect it. I'm not too familiar with it, but there are verifier functions you can use to ensure your file is a valid FlatBuffers file.

Comment: Ok, Thank you a lot, I will try to use desktop pattern to open my model.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646958/how-to-know-tensorflow-lite-models-input-output-feature-info) in first answer is guide, how to create json view of .tflite model. There you can see quantized values