# How to know which tensor to choose from the list of tensor names in Graph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to export a Linear Classifier to a tflite format. That's why I need to select a tensor from the tensor list names in Graph.

For example for exporting a DNN classifier model the following input and output tensor were chosen:

```
input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/concat:0")
    input_tensor.set_shape([1, 4])
    out_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0")
    out_tensor.set_shape([1, 3])
```

but for a Linear Classifier I don't know which one to use

I already print the list of tensors using:

```
for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
print (str(op.values()))
```

from that list I chose:
 input_tensor =

sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(**"linear/concat:0"**)
        input_tensor.set_shape([1, 4])

but the shape doesn't correspond, I imagine that it is because the linear classifier works different as the DNN, but then how can I know which input tensor to choose?

Comment: @Pannag Sanketi Do you know how to know this? Thank you

Comment: @PannagSanketi Do you know if there is some documentation of how to choose the right tensor depending on the premade classifier

Comment: +Jorge Jiménez we met the same problem. the converted tflite model perform different from the frozen pb model. The accuracy of tflite is lower than the pb file. any suggestions?