# tensorflow lite issue : output labels file size is fixed ?? output or input tensor dimension mismatch issue in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, bytebuffer, tensor, tensorflow-lite

Demo is available by Tensorflow in following link :

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/java/demo

Please change labels.txt file in above file by adding or removing a text(class) , It'll crash the application.

It's making the given solution unable to change output's size.

Please address the solution, how can we change the `label.txt` file with some constants like `INPUT_SIZE` or `OUTPUT_SIZE` that makes this bug solved.

**Note**

Application works fine as it is, but crash upon changing `label.txt` file, e.g. adding or removing names in the file.

**Crash :**

Cannot copy between a `TensorFlowLite` tensor with shape [1, 1001] and a Java object with shape [1, 1000].

****Above demo is build by using already present `gradle` configuration setting.**

**Feature request:**
Changing label file size & work accordingly through parameter is available in `IOS` demo with this
`output_size = 1000;`
This feature should be in Android version as well.

**Thanks.**

Comment: The above scenario is really above the documentation available, please provide some link if it could solve the issue?? Thanks

Comment: It seems like you should report this issue to that github project. This question appears to be asking SO to debug this project.

Answer (score 0):

As a feature request, you should generally file things to Github.

If you're looking for a local fix, I'm guessing the issue is that the model outputs a 1x1000 and you'll need to modify the actual model to be 1x1001 (and all the shapes of everything that comes before it).

Comment: Thanks,
I'm not sure, if it's possible to re-shape or refactor number of classes (=1000) programmatically in Tensorflow Android SDK, Otherwise I have to train model again for specific number of classes.

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't be able to programmatically do so and training the model may be the simplest path if you have it setup. What you can consider is manually modify the model (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50764572/how-can-i-test-a-tflite-model-to-prove-that-it-behaves-as-the-original-model-us for how to produce a json version of the model). However, I would assume that the model has several layers that assume the output shape being 1000, so unless there is something special, you'll have to start from training the model.

Comment: Otherwise, if there's a label you don't want, just remove it and add the one you want .. and then use transfer learning/retraining instead of training the model from scratch.